# How to use an external file which is including the input data in a Fortran program?

Tags: file, fortran

I am new to `Fortran` and want to ask a very simple question. I got some result form a `Finite Element Method` software and going to use the file in a program that I am writing in Fortran.

It would be appreciated if someone tell me how to entry the data from an external file into a program, although I am familiar with the OPEN statement, but do not know how to address the external file (like `.txt`, `.dat`, `.for`) through the program.

You can assume that the file is located on the path like this:

> D:\temp\data.txt

Comment: Your question is very broad... Could you narrow it down a little?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you study some examples, tutorials? There are tons of them on the internet.

Comment: Thank you Tolga, but I thought that is narrow enough. I just intend to input some data from an external file into a Fortran program instead of manual input data.

Comment: Not narrow at all! Did you read something about reading text files? How do the files look like? How do your data structures look  like?

Comment: You suppose there are two kinds of data like, x and y , and also there is a function like F(x,y) and I am writing a program to calculate the values of F. Besides, there are a huge amount of x and y and I can not able to entry them manually into Fortran and tend to write a program which has access to a text file which is including pairs of (x,y) data and read data from the file.

Comment: Do not use comments. Edit your question, so that your problem is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran 77 example (no stricter tags in your question) in which you write a program that reads user input, applies an *invariant transformation* to the input and outputs the results of the computation, like this

```
% cat test.f
      read(5,*) x, y
      write(6,*) x
      write(6,*) y
      end
% f77 test.f
% ./a.out
3 4
   3.00000000    
   4.00000000    
%
```

where I have manually input, from the terminal, values for `x` and `y`.

Now I have a file, produced by FEM, whose name is `data.txt`, let's see its content

```
% cat data.txt
3 4
%
```

A reasonable assumption that you could make is that fortran programs respect `stdin` and `stdout` redirection as all the other programs, but you're not sure until you try it with your hands

```
% ./a.out < data.txt
   3.00000000    
   4.00000000    
%
```

It works.  If you have other questions, could you please try to be more specific?

Comment: thank you for all the answers. thanks. Now I figure out that my question was broad as you mentioned and you were right.